# How to grep -o without the -o

Tags: bash

I've got BusyBox v1.01 providing my commands.  Hence, -o is not included in the grep.  How can I get `grep -o` behavior without the ... -o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `sed` you can use simple regex. (see [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/sed-emulation-of-grep-o-580625/))

```
sed -n 's/.*\(PATTERN\).*/\1/p' FILE
```

So to find only the text `StackOverflow` in a file `file.txt` you'd write

```
sed -n 's/.*\(StackOverflow\).*/\1/p' file.txt
```

Remember the pattern in the sed command is a regular expression. So If your pattern contains any meta characters of regular expression, they need to be escaped.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. thanks! I knew sed was probably involved, i'm weak with regex.

Comment: This will only print the first match on a line; `grep -o` prints all matches.

Comment: @tripleee Did you test? I tested it.

Comment: Didn't test until now, but when I did test, it behaved exactly like I describe, unsurprisingly. By contrast, `grep -o b <<<ababa` prints both matches.

Comment: I imagine the busybox `sed` doesn't support non-greedy matching, either. Anyway, if the OP is satisfied with a line-based solution, there is no need to fix it.

Comment: `sed` does not support 'non-greedy' concept.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: That's not a valid test of what tripleee is talking about: multiple matches *per line*.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` solution:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{match($0,/PATTERN/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Perl instead:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while /(pattern)/g' FILE
```

Comment: My busybox doesn't have Perl.

Comment: yea, perls a no go. If its got busybox, it probably doesnt have perl.