# mimicking `grep --only-matching` in awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I've got a `bash` script that handles a bunch of input and then prints out prettily-formatted output. At the moment it's very modular -- it spawns tons of subshells and uses `echo`, `grep`, `sort`, `wc`, & `sed` a lot, but I'm working on replacing the functionality of multiple chunks with larger `awk` chunks, for better efficiency.

One struggle: I've been trying to figure out how to search input for specific strings, only printing the exact thing I'm searching for. I've been playing with awk's `match` function but haven't had any success yet. Here's an example of one thing I'm trying to figure out how to integrate into a larger awk script:

```
$ egrep -o "pae|lm|vmx|svm|ht" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
ht
lm
pae
vmx
```

If I were to use awk to do the same thing, I'd want to end up with an array or variable containing each string I searched for that it found. The main problem as I see it is that each string I'm searching for might exist more than once in the input. Maybe I just need to buy an awk book... Any feedback welcome.

Comment: [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372783/how-to-grep-o-without-the-o)

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`, perhaps this is what your looking for, or may at least contain some helpful code:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) if ($i ~ /^(pae|lm|vmx|svm|ht)$/) array[$i]++ } END { for (j in array) print j }' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Output on my system:

```
vmx
pae
lm
ht
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks steve. That gives me some new stuff to chew on.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do your job:

`awk -v RS="pae|lm|vmx|svm|ht" 'RT != "" {print RT}' /proc/cpuinfo`

Or if you also need to do sorting in awk:

`gawk -v RS="pae|lm|vmx|svm|ht" 'RT != "" {m[RT]} END{n=asorti(m, m_sorted); for(i=1;i<=n;++i){print m_sorted[i]}}' /proc/cpuinfo`

**Explanation**: we set record separator `RS` to necessary regex, and awk stores the exact match of the `RS` regex in the `RT` variable. `RT` is empty for the last record, so we need to check for non-emptiness.

The sorting version uses function `asorti` which is `gawk` extension.

For more general approach, look into `match` function. For example, if you can set such record separator so match occures only one time per record, then the solution isn't complicated:
`gawk -v RS="your_separator" 'match($0, /pae|lm|vmx|svm|ht, m)" {print m[0]}`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll see if I can get what I need out of it when I get back to my coding machine.