# Print only matching word, not entire line through grep

Tags: unix, grep, solaris

I am familiar with shell programming in bash, but for some reason `egrep -o` to print only matching words is not working and displays error as below.

Environment is ksh unix console on putty and not linux or ubuntu terminal......any advice is appreciated!

Terminal input & output :

```
AB12 $ echo "i am a boy" | grep -w "am"
i am a boy
AB12 $ echo "i am a boy" | egrep -o "am"
egrep: illegal option -- o
usage: egrep [ -bchilnsv ] [ -e exp ] [ -f file ] [ strings ] [ file ] ...
AB12 $ echo$
ksh: echo$: not found
AB12 $ echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh
AB12 $ echo "i am a boy" | grep -o "am"
grep: illegal option -- o
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
AB12 $
```

**PS :** Similar thread but tried already : **[Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)**

Comment: You should copy/paste code/terminal output, rather than post a screenshot. Your screenshot is difficult to read, you can't copy/paste from it, and can't edit it (should this be required).

Comment: It looks like you're not using GNU grep; which OS are you using? Does `grep -V` or `grep --version` say anything about the version?

Comment: posted screen shot not visible properly. Also as 5K rep people should post question nicely.

Comment: @Jayesh : updated with code! :)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker : it says : `Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .`

Comment: You need to download the GNU grep version,[from](http://www.sunfreeware.com/introduction.html)

Comment: @Jayesh : this is a remote server, installation is not in my hand...i need some solution through programming only!

Comment: if you don't have gnu grep and don't have gnu awk either. I hope you have nawk on your SunOs. There is no shortcut to print those matched part out, you have to use nawk's `match()` and get the matched position and length, extract it, print, then search next match.

Comment: @Tiago : nope...but i really liked your answer, +1 to it!!  :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am assuming this is a Solaris box you are connecting to. Solaris' version of `grep` does not have the `-o` option. So you can either

- install the GNU grep on your Solaris box (it might already be installed in `/usr/sfw/bin`, or you might have luck with `pkg install //solaris/text/gnu-grep`); or
- use awk instead (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380039/mimicking-grep-only-matching-in-awk))

See on my box:

```
$ uname
SunOS
$  echo "i am a boy" | grep -o "am"
grep: illegal option -- o
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
$  echo "i am a boy" | /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -o "am"
am
```

Comment: any way to identify the *solaris box*?

Comment: maybe try `uname -a`?

Comment: See the output of uname -a

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu : its says `SunOS **************************************` had to *hide* server details :)

Comment: Ok `SunOS` is sufficient to conclude a Solaris box. Try the alternatives proposed in my answer.

Comment: @damienfrancois : `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep` did the trick...what is it exactly?? Main library bin files??

Comment: `/usr/sfw/bin/` is the path where the GNU version of the UNIX utilities are installed by default on Solaris (when installed)

Answer (score 5):

If you have `perl` :

```
echo "I am a boy" | perl -lne '/am/ && print $&'
am
```