# grep with regex printing only match

Tags: regex, grep

0

I made my regex and it works perfectly on my regex making tool. But when I try to use my regex in my command line it doesn't work, or at least it seems I cannot use that.

my regex is:

```
.*\[(GET|POST|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)\].*
```

it matches the call method no matter where it is I want it to be displayed in a simple file containing all calls.

i tried many commands, one of which is:

```
cat myfile.txt |  awk /'\[(GET|POST|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)\]/ {print $1}'
```

but it returns me the first column, although the matching group 1 is the method.

could anyone help me please?

I can provide an example if needed.

examples:

two possible inputs:

> 32.45.53.01, 32.32.32.543, 21.32.54.675, 21.32.54.779 161.21.34.56 [10/Mar/2020:13:04:14 +0100] [HTTP/1.1] [GET]
>   [-://yahoo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/libero/home] 302 - EL=[22ms,
>   -] WAS=[mediaworld_b2c:3213] - WAS=[-] - - [spam]
>
> 10.40.23.483 10.8.21.321 [10/Mar/2020:15:18:06 +0100] [HTTP/1.1] [GET] [-://google-preprod.test.com/sda/v1/ticrcv/TSY-JKidsahjsdaAO-A-JYVS5gGFxZ8PY8J-GRs0g-GOB2C]
>   200 108 EL=[17ms, -] WAS=[-] - -

and the output in both case has to be just:

**GET**

Comment: The awk command `{print $1}` is NOT for printing the first match. The variable `$1` is the first field resulting from awk's record splitting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527431/520567

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I well understand, but is that what you want?

```
grep -oE '\[(GET|POST|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)\]' myfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I kind of want something like this, but this command doesn't print only the method. it prints many columns, and I can't understand why

Comment: @topolino: Please, edit your question and add some input lines and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Toto seems to fit your needs. So for information, in awk `$1` refers to the first input field on the line (as dawg pointed out) and back references are not supported. However if you have GNU awk then you can use the `match` function which supports an additional parameter to store the captures this way :

```
awk 'match($0, /\[(GET|POST|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)\]/, a) { print a[1] }' myfile.txt
```